# Distinct columns after "ORDER BY" in SQL server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to distinct columns after **ORDER BY points.pPoint**. 
this is points table diagram:
[image] 

I want something as following image on the right side but getting result as the left side:

[image]

and this is my code:

```
SELECT TOP(6) MedicalExpertise.meid
FROM   physician INNER JOIN
       MedicalExpertise ON physician.meid = MedicalExpertise.meid INNER JOIN
       points ON physician.phId = points.phID
ORDER BY points.pPoint DESC
```

Comment: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
SELECT   DISTINCT meid
FROM     (   SELECT   TOP ( 6 ) MedicalExpertise.meid
             FROM     physician
                      INNER JOIN MedicalExpertise ON physician.meid = MedicalExpertise.meid
                      INNER JOIN points ON physician.phId = points.phID
             ORDER BY points.pPoint DESC ) d
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Comment: no, I want to receive distinct after group by with **points.point**.

Comment: I think, you mean that you want to get distinct on top of those  top 6 with highest points

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it returns the wrong value.
it returns:

        meid
--------------
1     |     5
2     |      4

do you see my image above?

Comment: It cannot return that resultset, since there is an extra line:
ORDER BY 1 DESC. Did you include it also?

Comment: I see that original query was also changed to: ORDER BY points.pPoint DESC. So I performed adaption of answer. This is a last my try. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use distinct keyword,
Ex:
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name;

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit the original question what you really want? Does it have to be grouped by any column before getting distinct? Please update the question.